# Como controlar a versão da documentação Swagger em .Netcore?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

Estou gerando uma documentação Swagger a partir de uma API em .Net Core, gostaria de saber se é possível através de notações separar na documentação quais são as APIs da minha versão 1 e versão 2 do meu sistema. Obs: Minhas apis usam na rota o número de versão da seguinte forma: Versão 1 = "/api/v1/" e versão 2 = "/api/v2/".

Comment: Disponibilize um código ?

Comment: Link parecido com a duvida: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46058930/swagger-not-working-correctly-with-multiple-versions-of-asp-net-webapi-app

Comment: Já ajuda, eu não sabia como pesquisar isso. Achei um tutorial da medium sobre isso: https://medium.com/@nelson.souza/net-core-api-versioning-d4f869fb9052. Vou tentar replicar e fechar a discussão caso funcione.